# Synchronization-Thread with Server every 5 secs

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services

I have a server-client environment, where the client connects and synchronizes data with the server every 5 second.

For synchronizing I use a background thread on the client which works fine, but on one specific hardware the method GetNetworkAvailable throws out of memory exceptions occasionaly. The errors occur whitout logic, so I guess somethings just not good with this hardware. Anyways I'd like to get your opinion on my background - polling function.

```
private void SynchronizedWorker()
{
    bool initialization = true;
    int initializationTries = 0;

    // Sync loop
    while (!_shouldStop)
    {
        // Initialize locals
        int syncInterval = _syncInterval; // Reset Sync Interval to default
        SyncStatus syncStatus = SyncStatus; // Get current Status
        bool hasNetworkConnection = true; // Has Network connection

        try
        {
            //*******************************************
            // Check Network connection
            //*******************************************
            if (!NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
            {
                hasNetworkConnection = false;
                _syncResetEvent.Set();
                syncStatus = SyncStatus.Offline;
            }
            else if (syncStatus == SyncStatus.Offline) // Is in offline - State, but Network available again recognize going online
            {
                _syncResetEvent.Set();
                hasNetworkConnection = IsServiceAvailable();
                // Sync-Status stays offline
                if (!hasNetworkConnection)
                {
                    // Wait 1 minute, before retry
                    syncInterval = 60000;
                }
            }

            //*******************************************
            // Proceed with Syncronisation
            //*******************************************
            if (hasNetworkConnection)
            {
                syncStatus = SyncStatus.Ok;
                // Try Initialization
                if (initialization)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // Sync initialization here...
                        // ..............................
                        ////////////////////////////////////
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        log.LogError(string.Format("Initialization Try {0}", initializationTries), ex);
                        syncStatus = SyncStatus.InitializationFailed;
                    }
                }

                // To many Init-Tries --> Stop
                if (initializationTries > 1)
                {
                    // Proceed
                    _syncResetEvent.Set();
                    _syncStatus = syncStatus;
                    break; // Stop Synch
                }

                // Debug
                var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

                // Do Up/Download
                if (!initialization)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // Synchronisation with service here...
                        // ..............................
                        ////////////////////////////////////

                        // Proceed
                        _syncResetEvent.Set();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        log.LogError("Download", ex);
                        syncStatus = SyncStatus.SynchFailed;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Set Sync status
            _syncStatus = syncStatus;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.LogError("Sync-Worker", ex);
            _syncStatus = Core.Sync.SyncStatus.SynchFailed;
            // Proceed
            _syncResetEvent.Set();
            // Reset Force
            _syncForce = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Set Completed
            if (OnSyncCompleted != null)
            {
                OnSyncCompleted(downloaded, uploaded, executed);
            }

            // Always Wait for Interval
            DateTime sleepuntil = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(syncInterval);
            while (sleepuntil > DateTime.Now && !_shouldStop && !_syncForce)
            {
                // Sleep
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }
    }

    // Stop
    _syncStatus = SyncStatus.Unknown;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would do the waiting for interval at the end also with an event - I find it cleaner. Something like this:

   ```
   AutoResetEvent _syncWaitEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

   ....

   // I assume there is a way for external callers to stop sync
   public void StopSync()
   {
       _syncForce= true;
       _syncWaitEvent.Set();
   }

   public void ForceSync()
   {
       _shouldStop = true;
       _syncWaitEvent.Set();
   }

   private void SynchronizedWorker()
   {
       ....
       // Sync loop
       while (!_shouldStop)
       {
           ....

           // wait for next interval or being woken up
           if (_syncWaitEvent.WaitOne(syncInterval))
           {
               // we have been signaled prior to the timeout expiring
               _syncForce = false;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. I would change `syncInterval` to a `TimeSpan` (`WaitOne()` expects one anyway and I don't like passing values around with implicit units. Just gets you in trouble some day)
3. It's not clear from your code what the `_syncResetEvent()` is used for. It's seems to be called in pretty much every case. You might want to revisit the name of it.
4. Add a log message in the `if (initializationTries > 1)` block to state that you are stopping sync because init failed too many times.